# Histogram using arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function

I am trying to use arrays from user input feeding into my histogram function and comparing the values in each instance of the array to have a counter to print out the number of "*" to show.

With the print of the histogram I am trying to divide it into bins i.e bin 9| *** for 3 instances of scores about 90, bin 8| ***** for 5 instances in the array of values 80 to 89 points and so on.

I have tried using pointer on bins[i] in my for loop however that wont work as well as I have tried &bins[i] but this only gives the address of 1 bin and does not display the subsequent bins or * from the counter in the array.

The following is the testing I am using to try and create this histogram. Case 1: 100, 95, 90, 85, 80, 75, 70, 65, 60, 40, 20, and 5. To make it shorter on code I will post my main and my function of Histogram. Thank you for your time.

```
int main()
{
    int scores[100];
    int bins[10];
    int counter[99];
    int count = 0;

    cout << "Enter a score (-1 to stop): ";

    do {
        cin >> scores[count++];
    } while (scores[count - 1] != -1);
    count--;
    Histogram(scores, count, counter);
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        ;
    {
        cout << &bins[i] << "| " << endl;
        for (size_t k = 0; k < counter[i]; k++) {
            cout << "*" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    deviation(scores, count);

    return 0;
}

int* Histogram(int scores[], int count, int counter[])
{

    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (scores[i] >= 90) {
            counter[k++];
        }

        else if (scores[i] >= 80 && scores[i] < 90) {
            counter[k++];
        }

        else if (scores[i] >= 70 && scores[i] < 80) {
            counter[k++];
        }

        else if (scores[i] >= 60 && scores[i] < 70) {
            counter[k++];
        }

        else if (scores[i] >= 50 && scores[i] < 60) {
            counter[k++];
        }

        else if (scores[i] >= 40 && scores[i] < 50) {
            counter[k++];
        }
        else if (scores[i] >= 30 && scores[i] < 50) {
            counter[k++];
        }
        else if (scores[i] >= 20 && scores[i] < 30) {
            counter[k++];
        }
        else if (scores[i] >= 10 && scores[i] < 20) {
            counter[k++];
        }
        else if (scores[i] < 10) {
            counter[k++];
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: What is the problem exactly? What happens when you compile and run your code? Do you get any errors? How does tyke output differ from what you want?

Comment: I do not have any errors when I compile and run. The output is as follows, Get user input of scores,  -1 to break input, shows address of bin " | " what I am after is 9| *** 
 8| **
 7| **
 6| **
 5|
 4| *
 3|
 2| *
 1|
 0| * Each on a separate line

Comment: Your historgram function doesn't make sense. It increments local variable `k` if `scores[i]` is less than 10, or greater than 90, or anything in between. It doesn't do anything.

Comment: The if statments are what i am trying to use to test the value in array scores[i]. If it is equal to that set rang(scores[i] >= 80 && scores[i] <90), k++ is used to show how many items from the array are in the specific rang then display an * based on how many times k is incremented.

Comment: Thanks for your help sincerely, I am not sure where I am going awry. I am going to scrap this project and start over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int k = 0;
counter[k++];
```

The above statement doesn't do anything. It increments `k` but it doesn't change the value of `counter[index]`. Maybe you mean `counter[k]++; k++;`?

```
if (scores[i] >= 90) counter[k++];
else if (scores[i] >= 80 && scores[i] < 90) counter[k++];
else if (scores[i] >= 70 && scores[i] < 80) counter[k++];
...
else if (scores[i] < 10) counter[k++];
else 
    printf("never reaches here!\n");
```

The `if/else` condition is wrong. `scores[i]` can be any value and it always satisfies the condition to infringement `k`, it never reaches the last condition.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++); <== extra ;
{
    cout << &bins[i] << "| " << endl;
```

There are other errors, it's not clear what the goal is. To print a historgram, you can try the something like the following (this will print a histogram rotated by 90 degree, I don't know if that's close to what you have in mind)

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<int> scores;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    scores.push_back(rand()%10);

for (int i = 0; i < scores.size(); i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < scores[i]; k++)
    {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

or print the histogram along the x-axis

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> scores;
    int max = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        scores.push_back(rand() % max);

    for (auto i : scores)
        cout << i << ", ";
    cout << "\n";

    for (int x = 0; x < max; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < scores.size(); y++)
        {
            if ((max - scores[y]) > x)
                cout << " ";
            else
                cout << "*";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. I am going to start over again using the vectors.

Comment: I think you just need the histogram I made, but you have to flip it by 90 degrees? You would have to modify the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it helps, it is for 10 input values with an integer range from 1 to 20!

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()enter code here
{
    int array[10]={0};
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
        cout<<"enter a number ";
        cin>>array[i];
        
    }
    for(int a=0; a<10; a++)
    {
        if(array[a]<=20)
        {
        for(int b=1; b<=array[a]; b++)
        cout<<"#";
        cout<<"\n";
        }
        else 
        cout<<"please enter number less than or equal to 20\n";
    }
}
```